# Mirrored wordpress installations

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation that I have cloned to create an app. I did so because the app site uses a theme developed to be mobile friendly. The site is regularly updated and edited so I have do all updates and edits twice. Is there a way to avoid having to double my work?

Comment: You could do a `rsync` every once in a while.

Comment: Thanks, now researching your comment. Don't know anything about rsync.

Comment: Recently I have collected a bundle of articles according to this topic: [Article 1](https://davidwinter.me/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/); [Article 2](https://deliciousbrains.com/storing-wordpress-in-git/); [Article 3](http://clintberry.com/2011/speed-up-your-wordpress-development-cycle-with-git/); [Article 4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/01/15/git-mirrors-for-wordpress/); [Article 5](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion).

Comment: Although I am seeking a way to do it simultaneously I've already seen enough t think that is a two step way to do it. Please ref me a place to see how (step by step) to execute it.